# Detecting beat frequency using FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I wrote Mathematica FFT code that works for non-beat signals, eg. Sin[2*Pi/20*x] and more complicated but I can't obtain beat frequency of Sin[2*Pi*(10)*x] + Sin[2*Pi*(11)*x]. Also, what is general approach for sampling of analytical functions or numerical data in order to extract beat freq, because I think there lies the problem? I understand that Nyquist theorem determines appropriate sampling frequency in order to extract high frequencies.

Code:

```
test[x_] = Sin[2*Pi/20*x]

xi = 0 
xf = 100
h = 1;(*(xf-xi)/n step*)
n = (xf - xi)/h (*# of sampling points*)

N[(1/h)/(n)]  (*sampling frequency*)

xg = N[Range[xi, xf - h, h]];
data = Map[test, xg]

cc = Abs[Fourier[data]]
ccred = Table[If[0 < i < Length[cc]/2, cc[[i]], 0.], {i, Length[cc]}];

Table[Ordering[ccred, -15][[i]], {i, 15}]
Table[ccred[[Ordering[ccred, -15][[i]]]], {i, 15}]

nu = Table[N[((Ordering[ccred, -15][[i]] - 1)*(1/h)/(n))], {i, 15}]
T = Table[N[1/((Ordering[ccred, -15][[i]] - 1)*(1/h)/(n))], {i, 15}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the beat, you have to *mix* (multiply) the signals, not add them. Try `Sin[2*Pi*(10)*x] * Sin[2*Pi*(11)*x`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)#Mathematics_and_physics_of_beat_tones  

I get the beat with this but i can't get beat freq via this code

Comment: John's point is that you *cannot* see the difference frequency in the raw FFT -- it isn't there. The FFT shows you the two sine waves and only the two sine waves. If you want to see the difference frequency, you will need to introduce a nonlinearity. Multiplying the two signals will work, taking the square of the sum will work.

Comment: I tried squaring and it does not work. Also what really interest's me are numerical solutions of some DE and there I will not have the opportunity to manipulate solutions like in this case.

Comment: The beat frequency is present in the linearly mixed signal, but it will not appear in the FFT.  Either introduce non-linear mixing or merely apply the textbook formula for beat frequency:  $f_b = |f_1 - f_2|$.

Comment: In the end it worked. I am not sure why was there problem earlier. Sometimes the beat freq is present in the linearly mixed signal, and sometimes it's not.

Comment: I understand mathematically that mixing creates the beat frequency in the spectrum.  However in acoustics, when 2 frequencies are played close together, the beat is "heard".  does this mean the beat doesn't exist in the FFT, but we perceive it anyway?  I wonder if that tells us something about how we process sound in our brain.

Comment: @Adrien Indeed, there's something interesting going on in the cochlea and the brain here. Beats are definitely audible, not just between closely-spaced frequencies. Remove the fundamental from a note, but not the harmonics, play it, and listeners will still hear the fundamental. To me, it smells like autocorrelation: an autocorrelation function has peaks at the beat periods. It's also insensitive to phase, like auditory perception. The cochlea has a structure like a delay line autocorrelator. I know this idea has floated around in psychoacoustics, but I don't understand its unpopularity.